# Can I group values together in a pivot table and only display those groups one at a time?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have multiple values in a pivot table that I would like to have first grouped and then possibly have a slicer for that pivot table where I can only show that group of values that correspond to the rows once at a time. I'm not sure where to start on this as I don't know how to group values.
[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xZiO.png)

Comment: What would be the criteria to group the values?

Comment: I think I was being misleading when I said "values". I have a few headers represented as 'values' within the pivot table (pictured in above image) that I would like to have grouped into three separate groups and then have those groups only displayed one at a time within the pivot through a slicer if possible. For example, one group representing 'Sum of CPM' and ' & '% difference from last month CPM' values. Another group for 'Sum of Revenue' & '% difference from last month Revenue' values and etc.